# How can I get both device id and device token before webview load?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Running on Xcode 8 with swift 3

Below is my ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var TestWebview: UIWebView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let deviceid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString

        //I want to pass device id and device token to this testURL
        let testURL = URL(string: "http://www.test.com/user.html?device=ios&deviceid=" + deviceid + "&devicetoken=")


        let testURLRequest = URLRequest(url: testURL!)
        TestWebview(testURLRequest)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

Below is my AppDelegate.swift file

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

        center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge], completionHandler: { granted, error in
            if granted {
                print("Yes。")
            }
            else {
                print("No!")
            }
        })

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

        return true
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {

        let deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
        print("===== deviceTokenString =====")
        print(deviceTokenString)
    }

}
```

Now, I can get device id in ViewController and also get device token in AppDelegate file.

However, how can I pass device token to my testURL in ViewController or how can I pass both device id and device token to testURL?

Comment: Make a property named `deviceTokenString`. Then feed this property where you used `reduce` method. Then from any of the view controller, get the `AppDelegate` instance and access `deviceTokenString`. (i.e: `guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            return
        } let deviceTokenString = appDelegate.deviceTokenString`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `deviceTokenString` a property in `AppDelegate` class.

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    ...
    var deviceTokenString: String?
    ...
    ...
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        // feed your property
        deviceTokenString = deviceToken.reduce("", {$0 + String(format: "%02X", $1)})
        print("===== deviceTokenString =====")
        print(deviceTokenString)
    }
}
```

Now, from any of the controller you can get your `deviceTokenString` like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
        return 
    } 
    guard let deviceTokenString = appDelegate.deviceTokenString else {
        // deviceTokenString isn't available
        return
    }
    // deviceTokenString is available here

    let deviceid = UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString

    // I want to pass device id and device token to this testURL
    // Concat various types into string like below
    let testURL = URL(string: "http://www.test.com/user.html?device=ios&deviceid=\(deviceid)&devicetoken=\(deviceTokenString)")


    let testURLRequest = URLRequest(url: testURL!)
    TestWebview(testURLRequest)
}
```

Comment: Appreciate! But I can not get my deviceTokenString and it run into else block.

Comment: Are you getting your logs for these lines from your _AppDelegate_: `print("===== deviceTokenString =====") print(deviceTokenString)`??

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, in my debug area, the last line is
 ===== deviceTokenString ===== and my device token

Comment: But it seems like it will run guard let deviceTokenString = appDelegate.deviceTokenString else {
       print("here first")
        return
    }

first and then print ===== deviceTokenString ===== with my device token, I think that is why I can not get device token in view controller.swift